# How to pop a value from cons list?

Tags: data-structures, rust, borrow-checker, cons

In the chapter 15.1 of The Book an example of `Box<>` usage for recursive type (cons list) implementation is shown. I tried to implement a method for this cons list to pop the outermost value out of the list, leaving the list with whatever left or `Nil` if nothing left. But it doesn't work, I can't figure out how to return the value while mutating the `self` after its deconstruction (and so borrowing?). Really none of the references in method make sense to me....

Is there no way to do this without creating a function that consumes the list and spits out both the value and new list?

Here is my code:

```rust
use crate::List::{Cons, Nil};

fn main() {
    let mut list = Cons(1, Box::new(Cons(2, Box::new(Cons(3, Box::new(Nil))))));

    println!("The first value is: {}.", list.pop().unwrap());
    println!("The second value is: {}.", list.pop().unwrap());
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum List {
    Cons(i32, Box<List>),
    Nil,
}

impl List {
    // It seems to me I need to mutably borrow the list to change it
    // but the way reference types behave later confuses me
    fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
        if let Cons(value, list) = &self {
            self = **list; // <- how to do this bit? self is borrowed...
            Some(*value)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mandatory reading if you want to play with linked lists: [Learning Rust with entirely too many linked lists.](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your approach work by first moving the current list out of `self`, and replacing it with `Nil`. This way, you can match on the old list and still be able to assign to `self`:

```
fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
    let old_list = std::mem::replace(self, Nil);
    match old_list {
        Cons(value, tail) => {
            *self = *tail;
            Some(value)
        }
        Nil => None,
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=743e2eb71cc4c25584db8497d65c62a7))

Comment: Awesome, yeah that works; haven't seen the `replace` function till now, looks pretty handy.